# Adding the percent symbol on the end of a number sequence in animation nodes

Tags: compositing-nodes, animation-nodes

[image: animation nodes]

The picture above shows the animation node setup I have currently. It is controlled by the movement of an empty. But I want to add a percent symbol on the end of the number. How can I do that? TIA

Comment: Why not just create a new text object that is a percent symbol, and move it off to the right of your animation?

Comment: 10 Replies. The 100% moves. Plus, It goes from 1 digit to 2 to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Join Texts** node (maybe "Join Strings" in your version) to concatenate multiple texts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Jacques Lucke has a more elegant method that mine.  Here is what your tree looks like with Jacques' addition.
[image: Jacques Variation]

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly how you have your number and the empty related to each other I was playing around with the animation nodes addon.

I set up my tree to look like yours and parented the TEXT object with the EMPTY.  When the empty moves around the text object changes the number shown.

As 10 Replies suggested, I was able to add another text object to the scene with just a '%' sign.  I parented that to the same empty in a position just to the right of the text object controlled by the animation nodes.  In order to get the two text objects to stay in relative position, the text object displaying the number needs to be set to RIGHT in the HORIZONTAL ALIGNMENT section of the PARAGRAPH settings for the text object.

[image: Text Data Tab]

Answer (score 0):

Jacques Lucke (@jacques-lucke) already gave the direct answer, but you can still spare some nodes/space:

[image]

(Using a "Join Texts" node, with the percent character as separator and with 2 strings as input - the number and an empty one.)